What would be a code compliant fix this double top plate?
I had to cut this top plate to get a beam through this wall to support rafters and effect a repair.
Well, that jobs done (thank you to several members whose advice was invaluable in getting this done) and the beam is out, now I have to do something about this top plate.
Framing inspection will be based on the 2015 IRC
This wall is not load-bearing. The double top plate runs the entire span across the doorway and is tied into the intersecting walls. The rafters and joists run parallel to it, and the bottom plate is removed.
My first instinct is to cut out the right most corner stud, remove the top and bottom floating sections of cut top-plate on the right side, trim the lower top-plate back to sit halfway on top a stud and trim the upper top plate further back by a foot to accommodate an overlapped/staggered splice using the upper top plate as a makeshift tension splice to the bottom by nailing from below.. but I can't find anything in the codes to support this action.
Any tips?




FYI those are joists, not rafters.  Unless your roof is flat?

@Huesmann, the use of "rafter" was appropriate in both cases, as far as we know.

@isherwood I am talking about the "rafters" which are sketched parallel to the ceiling—effectively horizontal.

That's technically also the rafter position. Let's not get too pedantic. :)

Your strategy is sound, but I'd make life easy on yourself and cut back a bit more. By taking more of the top plate out you create access to the double plate.
This sketch shows one possibility. The 32" stagger of the butt joints should be just fine. I can't quote code, but I can't see any inspector getting cranky about it.
(Reverse the laps of the plates to properly mate with the intersecting wall if I have them backwards.)

Use a reciprocating saw with a long, flexible blade to get at any nails.

I need to mention, when the short piece is removed, there is a strong chance that there is a nailer on top of that plate to hold the sheetrock ceiling in that corner. When pulling down on it after it is cut with a sawzall, it may try to pull the ceiling down in the corner. It will be tough to cut the nails if it is set up this way, since the joint that the saw blade needs to go into is above the ceiling surface of the drywall. Careful prying, may get you where you need to go. If the nailer is lapped onto the bearing wall in the corner, it will be a tremendous help.
